# Understanding the mechanism behind voting reversal

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Consider a scenario with two users, **User A** and **User B**. For whatever reason, **A** does not see eye to eye with **B**, and has taken it upon themselves to show their displeasure by downvoting **B**'s answers en-masse.

Now, **B** waits 24 hours, and failing a reversal, raises a custom moderator flag.

A moderator steps in, and voting is corrected. Happy ending? Not yet.

**A**, frustrated, *continues* to downvote, but this time, slips up, and ends up downvoting one too many times within a certain time span. Now, this targeted downvoting is *picked up by the system* and *automatically reversed*.

Now, since **A** was behind this the second time, and since the user was previously dealt with by a moderator, **does the system bring this second wave of targeted downvoting to moderator attention?**

It would make sense to do so, because it is apparent that the user did not learn that what they are doing is *completely against site rules*, in addition to being unfair to **B**, because you are voting on the user, not on their answer's merits.

**Context**

Yes, yes, I know. "It's one downvote, get over it". But it isn't
*just* one downvote. Say, **B** posts a *good* answer to a new question (let's assume for the sake of discussion that the question is
*good*, and on topic), and **A** then proceeds to downvote it. Any seasoned answerer will understand that few first few moments after
posting your answer are critical, because it  pops up at the top of
the question (as "1 new answer to this question"), and everyone who
sees it pop up will click (and likely vote). In that time, if a user
sees the answer being downvoted (by **A**), they are more likely to
dismiss it. Things worsen when **A** decides to upvote the
competition, letting **B**'s good (possibly better) answer slip to the
bottom of the pile, where it has less chances of being seen or
recovering.

I know what you're thinking now, "It's one answer, get over it".
But it isn't *just* one answer. Rinse and repeat the process for 5
answers and you're no longer enjoying the Stack Overflow experience. Yes, the moderators will roll the votes back, but by then, the damage has already been done.

So, I'd like to know whether moderators are automatically notified of foul play even when the system intervenes.

If not, I strongly suggest that they should be.

Comment: Since you had a lot of backstory, just wanted to make sure I get the gist... you are interested in understanding how multiple occurrences of serial voting are handled when 1 or more of the occurrences are handled automatically?

Comment: @psubsee2003, that is my question, yes.

Comment: I believe (a mod can possibly confirm) that moderators aren't involved at all, but the voting reversal script is fully automated. Posts explaining it have been a bit vague on purpose, to avoid people being able to cheat it.

Comment: As far as this goes: _"Rinse and repeat the process for 5 answers and you're no longer enjoying the Stack Overflow experience"_. Speaking as someone who gets revenge-downvoted semi-routinely, with the down-votes very infrequently rolled back, it's better to just "get over it" (as you say). It used to anger me, and I will admit even now I still get bothered by it occasionally. But, my enjoyment of the site comes from the moments when another person is _helped_. I have found that when my enjoyment is undermined by things that I should be ignoring, it's better for me to take a break from the site

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry, brainfarted on that. Please check now, it should be consistent.

Comment: thanks...that seems better :)

Comment: several years ago reversal script worked in such a way that ["the guy who serially voted you once, will have harder time trying it next time, even if they vote less..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773) Hope it still works that way

Comment: I think it would be better if the question were edited so the scenario doesn't involve moderators reversing the votes. Moderators do not have the ability to reverse votes, or even to _see_ individual votes.

Comment: @DavidZ Yup, you're right. They'd ask a CM to do it.

Comment: Semi-related - is there any detection of serlal upvoting, like someone using puppet accounts to get a main account to higher rep levels ?

Comment: A moderator can also put an account on a suspension for a cooling period. I've seen it happen twice in the last month or so. That should probably stop any very determined serial downvoter.

Comment: @gnat unfortunately, I can't see that happening. I have had two reversals (+16 and +12), and I am still continually being downvoted on a daily basis. These are not rolled back until I have to raise a custom flag and beg the moderators to look at it

Comment: hmm it looks like something broke in the system later, after I made above observation. I have suspected something like that because I regularly raise custom flags on cases of voting fraud of the kind that seemed to automatically revert in the past. That's sad

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, moderators are not notified of automated reversals, but we can see that they have happened and where the votes came from before they were reversed.

If this is happening to you, *more than once*, flag for moderator attention and we can see if this is someone that needs a sterner talking to.

It should be noted that the vast majority of such downvote revenge sprees are done in a unguarded moment, and are not repeated, and don't need moderator intervention. As such I really don’t see a need to auto-flag these cases; any real abuse would be lost in the noise.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you believe it would be appropriate to have moderators notified about automated reversals in this case?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: no, it'd be useless and way too noisy for us to see the cases that need actual attention.

Comment: This post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed/212339#212339 is also highly relevant

Comment: Can you give any idea of the scale of the problem that the automated script addresses?  Is it 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000 or more instances of down-voting sprees per 24 hours?  (How noisy is the "way too noisy" volume?  How has that volume trended over the last few years?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I can't, because I have no means to get exact numbers; that level of database access would require an employee. I based my assertion on the number of times I see reversal events when investigating accounts. For the most part *there is no real problem* as the system self-corrects and people move on. Given the number of flags we already get and given that we really don't see repeat offenders all that often or see repeat offenders get away with it for long, I really don't see a need to clutter up our already-very-busy flag queue with those events.

Comment: "... where the votes came from before they were reversed" I thought votes were anonymous? Or are "potential serial votes" recorded additionally?

Comment: @chade_: Moderators can see vote *patterns*, not individual votes. Reversals are logged as a summary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, this make way more sense know. Thanks for clarifying.