# Targeted closing of questions that I answered

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Following a disagreement in a chatroom, a user took it upon themselves to go through my answer history and close questions where possible. It seems they might be trying to delete the questions as well since an "off-topic" question was deleted around the same time that the others were closed. I don't really care about the rep hit that will result from this - it's just the targeted aspect of it that irks me. One of the questions is from 2015 so it's pretty clear to me that this isn't a coincidence:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083701/how-is-my-python-function-invallid/33084606
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220474/seeing-following-error-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-while-accessing-v/48220535
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219060/how-to-write-a-python-solution-in-one-line/48219081

Note the short timeframe in which these questions were closed.

In general, is it appropriate to indirectly target a user by going through their profile and closing questions they've answered?

Comment: closing doesn't change your rep, so there should be no rep hit anyway.

Comment: @Patrice It's my understanding that questions can be deleted when closed as off-topic.

Comment: hmmm yes. There are rules however where depending on age and score, you may not get a rep hit. You'd need to check for all the rules of the "roomba" to be able to get a more precise view of what would be deleted/remove the rep gains you've had.  In any case, it is really iffy if it's ok or not...

Comment: I get that no one should go through your content exclusively and target what you post. But if all these questions are appropriately closed... it's moderation working as it should. I mean short of the duplicate, it's not like the user single-handedly closed the questions.... Should they have gone through your profile to look up stuff to close? no, not at all. Is the stuff being closed is being wrongly closed? not that I can see...

Comment: @Patrice I agree that closing them is fair, it's just the manner in which that was decided that I don't feel is right.

Comment: I totally agree with that. I don't think anyone should just browse through your content to find these kind of things. I am on the fence because, arguably, properly moderating off-topic questions is a good action for the site. I agree the way they found all these questions is definitely iffy... anyway I personally am on the fence here, even if I definitely get where you are coming from. I would likely see it like you if it was my profile & content :/

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260840/2301450)

Comment: You should update your question to make it clear that the problem is that the questions are getting deleted, not just closed. (The 3 questions you link to all still exist and the post currently just talks about closure.)

Comment: @BSMP I assume there are delete votes cast on each of these then?  THAT is definitely a problem :/. I don't see a reason to delete any of these questions,  as Makoto is saying below :/

Comment: Your suspicions that these are targeted aren't that far off, even if I don't know the context of your disagreement with said user. In fact, choosing to target questions a user has answered, rather than their questions, probably isn't that rare since not everyone asks questions, and targeting their posts directly would just be too, well, direct.

Comment: Side note: you really should remove "How to write a Python solution in one line?" from list of examples of inappropriate behavior...  Answering question when you know (or should have known) of good duplicate existence is generally not welcome.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Generally not welcome? Is that why the answer is +6? Despite that, it being an unwelcome answer doesn't really excuse the behavior I'm trying to show.

Comment: There are enough people who believe that answering the same question as many times as possible improves SO overall... There are couple who believe otherwise (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+known+duplicates).

Comment: If you really into discussing topic of going through answers and voting - consider instead to come up with valid "feature-request" that solves problem when one notices "I believe content by this user is not up to site's standards" in a way that such person don't need themselves to go through the questions/answers and act, but rather some other "safe" mechanism (unlikely "let moderators review content" would be solution - you'd need better one). So far on SO one can consistently produce bad answers there is not much can be done in non "targeting specific user" way...

Comment: @Patrice I had written an answer pointing out that the closed questions couldn't be roombaed and the OP commented that a question where their answer had a positive score and was accepted had already been deleted.

Comment: [Is this the related discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40809084#40809084)? that's not very spectacular...

Comment: @Cerbrus the discussion started with [this message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40805311#40805311) and continued [on the next day](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40811798#40811798)

Comment: Jacob, You said: _"my position on the matter is that I'm going to continue answering "bad questions" so long as it helps the author. If the question inevitably gets closed and deleted - whatever, I'm just satisfied with being able to help them."_ In that case, you're actively contributing to __lowering the standards of SO__. You shouldn't be surprised to find questions you're answering are getting closed.

Comment: _"If it's going to be closed and deleted then why care if it's answered?"_ ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40813148#40813148)) Because the act of answering a typo question prevents that typo question from being automatically deleted.

Comment: And if you were answering without regard about the questions being closed/deleted afterwards; **why this meta post?**

Comment: CV-ing as _"Not interested in input"_. From the discussion on my answer here, it's very clear the OP only wants one specific answer, and isn't interested in anyone that says otherwise.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not interested in answers that hardly explore the question at hand.

Comment: Let's not repeat that discussion here.

Comment: Regarding your new edit (that also changes the original scope a bit): Possible duplicate of [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think there's a difference between closing+deleting and downvoting.

Comment: @JacobWood I agree, but I would say that targeted downvoting is the worst offence of the three. It's completely anonymous, and even mods have only limited tooling to inform themselves. And downvoting has the loosest guidance for when it's appropriate; it's the most subjective of the three options by far. If the official verdict is that even serial _downvotes_ can be appropriate as long as you're legitimately voting on content rather than the user, I'm certain this implies that closing and deletion is just even more appropriate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, let's get things out in the open. Near as I can piece together, this all started because a user was fairly rude to you in their comments on your third answer above. Those comments were inappropriate, and should have been flagged and removed. This should have stopped then.

Instead, as a response to that you engaged this person in the comments on another answer and in chat. You also started serially downvoting their posts ([related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362002/understanding-the-mechanism-behind-voting-reversal)). At the same time, they started serially downvoting your posts (something they failed to mention in that Meta post, for some reason) and carrying on some harsh arguments with you.

I tried to clean up the comments as best I could, and I requested votes to be invalidated between the two of you (the votes were wiped yesterday). I hoped that would stop this feud, but it apparently has not.

Should some of these questions have been closed? Probably. However, I'm uncomfortable with the targeted nature of the close / delete votes here. I'd really prefer it if both of you would walk away from each other and let this die out.

Comment: "something they failed to mention in that Meta post, for some reason"... that meta post was made after the second wave of downvotes I received. Not the first. I decided to walk away, but the downvotes did not stop.

Comment: And, in my defence, _yes_, the votes were on this specific user, but they were, in my mind at the time, [justified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260840/2301450), as they were poor answers to poor questions. _Not_ the best way to do things, and I can understand that.

Comment: I'll say one more thing, in _OP's_ defence. This user has received flak from a LOT of other users about answering poor content on the site. Consequently, more than one person(s) have been closing questions and downvoting the answers. I can see how, following our disagreement, those downvotes could all be attributed to me, and hence the retaliation. However, after I decided to start going through their profile to close bad questions (around yesterday), I did not downvote a single answer of theirs. I cannot stress this enough.

Comment: Please consider following the rest of the discussion (and it's conclusion), [here, under Cerbrus' answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362016/targeted-closing-of-questions-that-i-answered#comment549212_362034)

Answer (score 21):

> *Is this behavior appropriate?*

Yes, it is. Closing questions that **should be** closed is always the correct action.

You've made it quite clear in chat that you [don't care](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40813148#40813148) that a question shouldn't be answered and that you [don't care](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40811899#40811899) that a question gets closed or deleted.
(As yivi [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362016/targeted-closing-of-questions-that-i-answered/362034#comment548789_362016): Then why post this meta question?)

It's not surprising that this admission leads to a user having a look at your profile, to see if you've answered more questions that should be closed. To be honest, it's quite an effective method of finding those questions that slipped through.

Sure, it may not be "nice" to specifically dig through your profile, but they're not specifically targeting *you*. They're just closing / deleting bad questions.

Questions that would've been [deleted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), if it weren't for the answers you (and others) added.

Comment: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: Yea, that's a good read as well, @gnat. Thanks.

Comment: A little [context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362016/targeted-closing-of-questions-that-i-answered#comment549141_362066) from my side to Brad Larson's answer, in case it was missed.

Comment: I would also not go far as to jump to conclusions that the OP is being "targeted by a single user", it takes 5 votes to close, and 3 to delete. In many cases, I have not casted the first vote there. In many cases, I have not even cast a vote. That means I'm not the only one closing questions they have answered. This really shouldn't be made about a single user (which, as it appears, that's how it is) because of personal vendetta.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What? From your own comment "yes, the votes were on this specific user". _You_ were going through my answers to find questions to close. That's the targeting that the question is about.

Comment: @JacobWood Yes, I did downvote, but not out of personal vendetta. Because your answers were _bad_, and answered bad questions. I was also courteous enough to tell you why I did so, which you seem to have ignored in this discussion. What was your reason for those 8 + how many ever other downvotes?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Per the (now updated) question - I would like the general idea to be discussed, not the specific case.

Comment: Furthermore, I am completely with Cerbrus here, this is moderation working as it should. Contrary to your belief, not a single downvote you've received over the last 24+ hours has come from me.

Comment: @JacobWood I don't see how you can discuss a general case if you are naming names and pointing fingers (as your post does, with the links). Understand? I'm not petty enough to hold personal grudges. I've even approved your edits on my questions.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The links were to aid in explaining the type of targeting I'd like to discuss. I purposefully did not name you in the question.

Comment: @JacobWood yes, but anyone with half a brain cell can click on those links and glean enough information to understand what has happened. You are severely underestimating the intelligence of the community.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What? My point is that the links aren't there so people can analyze this specific case.

Comment: So why _are_ the links there then? You could've linked to any random closed post. Or even, with some searching, 2 closed post with answers from the same user.

Comment: @JacobWood I have to apologise to you for my brazen behaviour during our first encounter, it was uncalled for. However, I have nothing else to apologise for. I hope that you take this as a positive learning experience to decide contributing more positively to the community. From this meta discussion, I hope it has become clear to you that your actions to this point as far as answering VLQs are concerned, are not welcome.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see why that would be helpful - the question is about targeting a specific user with multiple close-votes. A random closed post does not demonstrate that.

Comment: @JacobWood I've said this before to you, and I will say it again, a little bit more respectfully. If you are going to _completely_ go against site policy, by putting the questioner before the community, then you will have to be prepared to see your time spent answering those questions flushed down the toilet.

Comment: @JacobWood At the heart of it, I think you are a sensible person, but overly stubborn. There are some times when it is better to admit you're wrong. I believe you are capable of writing good answers, as I have seen from your profile. I think your time is wasted answering bad questions, as it encourages more bad quality, and wastes others' time as well. I can promise you, that if I were to come across you writing  _good_ answers to _good_ questions, I would upvote them. I am going to bury the hatchet, and I hope there are no hard feelings from your side as well. All the best.

Comment: Interestingly, I've been getting quite a few downvotes on main since I posted this answer, on answers that weren't downvoted before. That's a little suspicious.

Comment: @Cerbrus time for a meta post!

Comment: @Cerbrus unfortunately, so have I. Mostly my 0/1 vote answers, so when the downvote is given, it shows up as -1. What's more, I notice the other answers (if any) or subsequently upvoted. I find it an annoyance to have to wait 24 hours to flag every new wave that comes in daily.

Comment: The flag was marked "helpful".

Answer (score -6):

You don't have enough reputation to see this, but...there may be a bit of abuse on the deletion feature here.

Let me start by saying that I don't exactly agree with *how* the questions were closed, but I do agree with two out of three closures.

First, [how is my python function invallid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083701/how-is-my-python-function-invallid/33084606) is at best either a typo or is missing more detail.  Whitespace in Python can be finicky at times.

Next, [How to write a Python solution in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219060/how-to-write-a-python-solution-in-one-line/48219081) is effectively asking how to do a list comprehension, which is along the lines of what was suggested in an answer.  The dupe has the solution, just the same as your accepted answer.  No real big deal there.

Lastly, [Seeing following error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:" while accessing views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48220474/1079354) is missing details, such as code (in plain text).

**However**, I'd like to call attention to all of these questions.  *None* of them are really worth *immediate* deletion, nor is the last one in particular a *bad* question at all!  Despite the fact that the OP's code is in pictures, **it's there**, and **there's a good answer for your question too**.  That question doesn't warrant deletion or closure in my mind; just some editing.

Comment: Minor correction - none of those are my questions, just questions that I had answered.

Comment: @JacobWood:  Good to know.  I kinda got tunnel vision there.  I feel my points are largely independent of ownership, so I'll do some surgery here...

Comment: The first question is about a __very__ common syntax error. There's even a canonical duplicate for it. I see no reason for that question to stay

Comment: The *last question in itself* is pretty much useless without the code. The question was open for 3 days with a comment asking for the code in the question itself but did not get updated. It is a) typo with b) no mcve.

Comment: And the last question wasn't deleted completely until the meta-effect brought it some deserved attention.

Comment: @Makoto All three questions deleted.

Comment: @JacobWood:  Yeah, I'm not thrilled about that...

Comment: @Makoto; Please consider following the rest of the discussion, [here, under Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362016/targeted-closing-of-questions-that-i-answered#comment549212_362034).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  I don't have many "warm-and-fuzzies" left now given that I've read that the commentators believe that the person shouldn't have answered bad questions.  Granted, the questions weren't *great*, but going out of our way to punish them for answering them seems incredibly counterproductive.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  A lot of people have misinterpreted me in thinking "punish" equates to "downvote", but let me stress that this isn't the case.  I'm simply referring to the perceived mentality I read when I saw the comment chain.  Even though the questions weren't the best, I'm just not that convinced that these actions (including deleting the questions) was done with the best of intentions.

Comment: This meta has polarised the community: one group is all for applying moderation powers, while another is concerned about the ethical aspect of it. Well, regardless of how "ethically" it is being done, those questions are better off being deleted. That the user's answers are also being removed is an unhappy byproduct of actions they should not have taken in the first place.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  Acknowledge that every moderation action taken by the community has its effect.  It's important to not just think about the use of your moderation tools when you're moderating content.  Again I throw out that the last question only really needed to be edited into shape for it to realistically be on-topic, since it had a decent answer, but the speedy deletion felt like an incredible overreach.  If you insist on only focusing on the moderation aspect in this, then **Stack Overflow's negative stigma will _never_ dissipate.**